# Keeping a partial view model self contained but still able to get data based on an outside selector

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

This question leads to more of a discussion of methods instead of specific code/debugging.

I am working on an MVC project using knockout for dynamic data binding with c# on the front end. I have a partial view model, I want to populate with a list of data objects.  I want to be able to do this without a postback using ajax calls using knockout for the data binding.  The data call will depend on an outside selection such as a dropdown select box.  What method/tool do I have available to me to keep this view model self contained without a dependency to a specific select box, but still be able to have the functionality I just explained?

Comment: If you are doing a data call after pageload, you need to use something like ajax. If you can get the data on page load through the model or viewbag, than just copy the data to a javascript var like `<script>var modelData = @'ViewBag.modelData';</script>` Or, if you really want to pass data back and forth apart from page load, you could look into SignalR.

Comment: I am using ajax currently